# Ionic Live Reload Unable to Load App on Android Phone

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm trying to run Ionic Live Reload, connecting to my phone using this command:

```
$ ionic cap run android -l --external
```

When I run the app in Android studio, the phone shows a white screen and the message:

> Unable to load app. Are you sure the server is running at http://192.168.1.59:8100?

I opened the port 8100 with no result (I'm using Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo ufw allow 8100
```

I read all the articles about connections problem, buy I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very silly problem, but perhaps this answer is useful for someone making the same mistake:

**I just was connected to different wireless networks**. So, I connected my phone and notebook to the same Wifi connection and that solved the problem instantly.